# Why does getOne(…) on a Spring Data repository not throw an EntityNotFoundException?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a weird issue, I was doing integration testing, calling my controller to get an object from database that doesn't exist.

```
public Optional<T> get(Long id) {

  try {
    return Optional.ofNullable(repository.getOne(id));
  } catch(EntityNotFoundException e) {
    return Optional.empty();
  }
}
```

When `getOne(…)` is not able to find anything, I was expecting an `EntityNotFoundException` but actually nothing. If I inspect my result I can see that I have an empty entity with a handler link to it "threw `EntityNotFoundException`" but we don't go in the catch and I return an optional of this weird entity.

I can't understand this behavior.

Comment: Why you expect an excpetion? The javadoc do not say about an exception.

Comment: That's the classic JPA behavior when you call getOne() on a non existing data.

Comment: Moreover I can see this exception is thrown but somehow handle, by spring data ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is due to the way JPA specifies `EntityManager.getReference(…)` to work. It's supposed to return a proxy that will either resolve the object to be returned on the first access of a property or throw the contained exception eventually.

The easiest way to work around this is to simply use `findOne(…)` instead, like this `Optional.ofNullable(repository.findOne(…))`. `findOne(…)` will return `null`in case no result is found.

A more advanced way of resolving this is to make the repository return `Optional` instances directly. This can be achieved by creating a custom base repository interface using `Optional<T>` as return type for the `find…`-methods.

```
interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

  Optional<T> findOne(ID id);

  // declare additional methods if needed
}

interface YourRepository extends BaseRepository<DomainClass, Long> { … }
```

Find a complete example of this in the [Spring Data examples repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/java8#support-for-jdk-8s-optional-for-repository-methods).

Comment: Looks like a good idea ! I'll give it a try rigth away 
But ... what about the performance, is findOne as good as getOne ?

Comment: There indeed is a difference as `getOne(…)` doesn't immediately materialize the object while `findOne(…)` does. The downside of the former is that it delays the failure in the lookup, too, which bites you here. Also, `findOne(…)` will hit the first level cache in the `EntityManager` so within a particular session, you won't hit the database twice. If this really becomes an issue you might wanna plug a cache explicitly but I'd delay that until measurement really shows, there's a problem.

Comment: it's worth noting that as of 2019, `CrudRepository` already brings `Optional<T> findById(ID id);` which does pretty much what this answer suggested in 2015...

Answer (score 6):

In Spring `@Repository` classes, the `getOne(id)` method doesn't always verify existence until the object is queried (by calling `entity.getId()` or something) so it's no-such-entity exception may be delayed. To validate right away, use `findById(id)` instead (which returns an `Optional<EntityType>` which will be empty if the entity with that id doesn't exist).

---

This is how it worked for me

```
public User findUserById(Long id) {
    return userRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
```