# Tests are passing when every asserts are in one test but fail when split

Tags: junit, spring-boot, spring-data

I have following code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TRConfig.class)
public class ARepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    ARepository aRepository;

    private A a = new A("value");

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        aRepository.save(a);
    }

    @Test
    public void findByValue1() {
        assertEquals(a, aRepository.findByValue("value"));
    }

    @Test
    public void findByValue2() {
        assertEquals(null, aRepository.findByValue("inv"));
    }
}
```

I have following error on second test, I don't know if first passes because second is the first one which runs:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find ...model.a.A with id 10; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find model.a.A with id 10
```

But when I do it like this, the test passes:

```
@Test
    public void findByValue() {
         assertEquals(a, aRepository.findByValue("value"));
         assertEquals(null, aRepository.findByValue("inv"));
    }
```

Why? What I have to do to make it running properly?

Here is my config:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = ARepository.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = A.class)
@Import({ DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class TRConfig {
}
```

Comment: Try to add `@Transactional` on `ARepositoryTest`.

Comment: Done, still doesn't work

Comment: Well, I have no clue about Spring; but I am wondering: could the problem be that your atBefore ... runs twice when you have two tests, but only once, when they within the same test? Guess what I am saying is: have you tried to move that statement from atBefore ... directly in your test method; and run it twice there?

Comment: Or you should add an (at)After to clear your repository, as you will add another record with each test you execute.

Comment: Show us the implementation of ARepository, or make sure you understand the code that actually interacts with the JPA EntityManager. In JPA, there is a difference between 'getting' and 'finding'. Getting will throw exceptions when the object does not exist. Find will return null. You need to figure out which one is used within ARepository.

Comment: This doesn't look like a testing problem, but rather with how spring data handles failed lookups. This related question suggests that *by design* the lookup failure is sometimes delayed, which looks exactly like the issue you're having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264758/why-does-getone-on-a-spring-data-repository-not-throw-an-entitynotfoundexcept