# LazyInitializationException when using DomainClassConverter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I would like to set a one to many relationship in a REST controller but I get a `LazyInitializationException`. I know how to solve that exception (JOIN FETCH, EntityGraph) but not in the context of the `DomainClassConverter`.

> The DomainClassConverter allows you to use domain types in your Spring
>   MVC controller method signatures directly, so that you don’t have to
>   manually lookup the instances via the repository

```
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Contract> contracts = new HashSet<>();

    public Company addContract(Contract contract) {
        this.agreements.add(contract);
        contract.setCompany(this);
        return this;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Contract implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

}
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface ContractRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {
}
```

A `POST /api/companies/1/contracts` request maps the `createContract` method. The parameters are mapped correctly, so I have a `Contract` and a `Company` instance. When I try to add the contract to the company I get the `LazyInitializationException`. I tried to add `@Transactional` to the method and call .size() on company.getContracts() to initialize the collection but it's throwing the same exception.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/companies/{companyId}")
public class CompanyContractResource {

    @PostMapping("/contracts")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Contract> createContract(@Valid @RequestBody Contract contract, @PathVariable("companyId") Company company) throws URISyntaxException {
        company.addContract(contract);
        Contract result = contractRepository.save(contract);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/contracts/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using `DomainClassConverter`. I changed the repository to fetch the lazy collection and then add the `Contract`.

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Company c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.contracts WHERE c.id = ?1")
    Company findByIdWithContracts(Long id);

}
```

In the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/companies/{companyId}")
public class CompanyContractResource {

    @PostMapping("/contracts")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Contract> createContract(@Valid @RequestBody Contract contract, @PathVariable("companyId") Long companyId) throws URISyntaxException {
        Company company = companyRepository.findByIdWithContracts(companyId);
        company.addContract(contract);
        Contract result = contractRepository.save(contract);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/contracts/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your controller method like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Contract> createContract(@Valid @RequestBody Contract contract, @PathVariable("companyId") Long companyId) throws URISyntaxException {

        // fetching a company explicitly 
        Company company = companyRepository.findOne(companyId); 

        company.addContract(contract);

        Contract result = contractRepository.save(contract);

        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/contracts/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
}
```

Related info: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482117/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32317367)

Comment: The `findOne` will not fetch the lazy collection.